# How many newtons are there in one coulomb of charge?

Tags: charge, theory, electron, field, electric-field

Or, I should have said, how many newtons of force does one coulomb of charge exert? At a distance, presumably, of one meter?  Since N/C is supposedly equivalent to V/m?

P.S.  What are the values for a single electron or proton?  The 'elementary charge'?  I suppose it would be the answer(s) to my first question divided by 6×10<sup>-19</sup> .....

Comment: Is this just about Coulomb's law?? Or something else? Are you worried about dimensions being correct?

Comment: I think there may be some confusion here about the difference between electrostatic force and the amount of (for example) force that can be generated by a motor or solenoid.  Energy (coulombs) is equal to force multiplied by distance, not force alone,

Answer (score 1):

One coulomb is equal to the charge on 6.241 × 10<sup>18</sup> protons. The charge on 1 proton is 1.6 × 10<sup>-19</sup> C. Conversely, the charge of an electron is -1.6 × 10<sup>-19</sup> C. A coulomb is an enormous charge - two 1 C charges that are 1 m apart exert a force of 9 × 10<sup>9</sup> newtons (see Coulomb's law)

Answer (score 0):

The electric field from a point charge \$q \$ at a distance \$ R\$ is
$$\textbf{E} = \mathbf{a_R} \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{q}{R^2} $$
where \$\mathbf{a_R} \$ is a unit vector pointing **radially** outward from the point charge.
If another point charge \$Q \$ is a distance \$R \$ from \$ q\$, then the exerted force on  \$Q\$ from the electric field is
$$\textbf{F}=\mathbf{a_R} \cdot\mathbf{E}Q = \mathbf{a_R} \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{Qq}{R^2} $$

You ask

> how many Newtons of force does one Coulomb of charge exert? At a distance, presumably, of one meter?

but as you can see from the above expression, the force exerted depends on the charge of **both** point charges. Also, a charge of \$q=1\text{C} \$ is a ridiculously huge charge!